# Add extra headers on Express NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to put some extra headers on the responses sent by a https server created with Express. For example, I want to set a X-Frame-Options response header.

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('../certificate/ca.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../certificate/ca.crt')
};

module.exports = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function (err) {
    if (err)
        return console.log(err);
    var uri = 'https://localhost:' + port;
    opn(uri);
});
```

I tried various things, but none of them worked. Did anybody manage to do such thing?

Comment: This is not created using express just to be sure as per your question. Also can you can what you have tried and how?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use Helmet in order to set the headers I needed.